# Event Listener not working inside plain old function () {}

Tags: javascript, react-native

I Created Application Instance as shown below.

```
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native'
function App() {
this.flag = {
  isConnected: false
}
...
return () => {
       NetInfo.addEventListener(
       'connectionChange',
         (__connectionInfo) => {
          if (__connectionInfo is not empty) {
          // check if network connection type is available
         // or not if not found than re-update flag to false.
         if (__connectionInfo.type !== 'none' && __connectionInfo.effectiveType !== 'unknown') {
           // update flag.
           this.flag.isConnected = true // <-- should be updated to App(this). if you try App.flag.isConnected it will return false
         } else {
           // update false network.
           this.flag.isConnected = false
         }
       }
     }) // network event listener.
   }
}

// calling instance.
let _morphine = new App()
_morphine = _morphine() <--- I am just importing this already created instance in every component for using it as system core handler for handling every task like saving data, updating notify network change using instance.
```

*** In actual code I have wrapped _morphine object into if else so that only single instance is created
whenever app launches first time on the user device.**

Problem:
1. I want to re-render my layout component on network change but it seems that network listener not updating this.flag.isConnected to true || false.
2. Above pattern for sharing system core throughout components is good by using single instance?

Comment: Your `App` function returns a function. Why are you talking of "instances" and invoking it with `new`?

Comment: to make App child object  available to App. so than i can App.Hello()

Comment: and second to return asynchrony. after it i can use async-await

Answer (score 1):

According to the [NetInfo Example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/RNTester/js/NetInfoExample.js), your event listener should look like this...

`NetInfo.addEventListener('change', this._handleConnectionInfoChange);`

Answer (score 1):

You were using `this` inside a normal function (your `App` component return a normal function, not an arrow one). That `this` is evaluated from the context where it gets called. For example, calling it in the global space like you did in your snippet will make `this` to be `global` and `this.isConnected` will be undefined. You have two options to fix this:

1. Return an arrow function inside `App`. Arrow function will bind `this` to the scope it is declared so you will have a constant `this`
2. Don’t use `this` and just use normal closure, declare `isConnected` as a function variable and your returned function will have access to it.

Regarding the question about singleton design like you did, personally I prefer making a component which have an internal state `isConnected`. Event handler can be placed in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`. Then you can use render props pattern to access the connection state

```
class NetInfo extends Component {
      state = {isConnected: false}

      componentDidMount() {
        // set up event listener
}

componentWillUnmount() {
        // remove event listener
}

render() {
return this.props.children(this.state.isConnected)
}

}
```

Comment: Highly appreciate your answer. and i am sorry for mistake it is arrow function. which my App component is returning. and if i do this.isConnected = true just above for before eventListner than it will work.